# NDB Query comparing datetime objects skips dates on same day

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, app-engine-ndb

I'm currently working on a project in which I have to compare two datetime objects while querying. My GQL query is:

```
qry = ndb.gql("SELECT * from Task WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 AND due >= :2 ORDER BY due ASC",
                          ndb.Key(urlsafe=group_key), datetime.now())
```

The field due is a datetime object. To save it, I got a UTC string as post data and parsed it using

```
frmt = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
first_event = datetime.strptime(utc_date_string, frmt)
```

What I want to do now is getting the first 5 entities where `due` is older as the moment right now. (Basically the next 5 events that happen).
However, my query only returns the next events that are happening from the next day and skips the ones from today.

I have played around with [gae-pytz](https://code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/) a little, but since I am new to handling dates in programming I wasn't able to solve the problem so far.

**EDIT:**
To observe a little what exactly is happening I created an task entity for three hours later on the same day. I saved the UTC string `Sun, 03 Nov 2013 07:10:00 GMT` which when converted back to my local time is **not** correct. **EDIT2:** Seems like AM/PM conversion on client side is not working.

Then I changed my query to get all entities without comparing the dates and then logged the current datetime and the datetime of my entity:

```
qry = ndb.gql("SELECT * from Task WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 ORDER BY due ASC",
                          ndb.Key(urlsafe=group_key))
```

When logging `task.due (logging.error(task.due))` I get:

```
2013-11-03 07:10:00
```

When logging `datetime.utcnow() (logging.error(datetime.utcnow())` I get:

```
2013-11-03 16:14:30.736933
```

So it seems like my `task.due` field is being saved in 12h format while `datetime.utcnow` is returning the time in 24h format.

I still haven't found out with what I need to compare, but at least now I know what to research for.

Comment: I use a lot of date sorting and selection and it always works reliably for me.  The important thing to remember is dates are stored without any tz.  You need to convert to UTC (if not already) on put(), and convert back to local timezone when displaying.  You haven't shown how you put entities.  Oh and are you certain the entries you want have the ancestor ?

Comment: Yes, the ancestor is correct.
Im getting a UTC string from JavaScript, convert it to a datetime object with the frmt string above and then put it as a datetime object into the DB.
My plan is to send it back as a UTC string and let javascript print it as a local time string.